# How to get part of string and pass it to other function in python?

Tags: python, string, function

My task is to verify whether string is valid date and time or not.

> "2013-01-01W23:01:01"

The date and the time are separated with the symbol 'W' or white space.
How can I get the first part of the string - "2013-01-01" and pass it to function `valid_date(value)` and the second part '23:01:01' to other function `valid_time(value)`
I tried:

```
def is_datetime(value):
    if(value.find[' '] >= 0):
        return is_date(value[:value.find[' '] - 1]) and is_time(value[value.find[' '] + 1:])\
```

but apparently I am not allowed to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.partition()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) to get the first part, fast:

```
value.partition('W')[0]
```

You could use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) as well, for Python versions < 2.5. Limit the split to just the first `W`:

```
value.split('W', 1)[0]
```

Either technique will always yield a result, even if there is no `'W'` character in `value`.

Demo:

```
>>> value = "2013-01-01W23:01:01"
>>> value.partition('W')[0]
'2013-01-01'
>>> value.split('W', 1)[0]
'2013-01-01'
```

Comment: Where would one use `partition` over `split` when they are both available, like in Python 3? Just curious.

Comment: @AlexThornton: When splitting just once to get the first or last part, `str.partition()` is faster and has the added benefit of always returning a 3-element list. That can make many usecases easier.

Comment: @AlexThornton: and `str.split()` and `str.partition()` are both available from Python 2.5 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this ,

```
>>> a="2013-01-01W23:01:01"
>>> a.split('W')
['2013-01-01', '23:01:01']
```

And then send `a.split('W')[0]` and `a.split('W')[1]` to the validation functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure whether it is a valid date or time, you should use regular expressions to validate the string, then you don't even need to call `is_time` and `is_date`.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})[W ](\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})$")
# ...
value = "2013-01-01W23:01:01"
match = pattern.findall(value)
if match:
  pass #is valid
```

This will test whether something *looks* like a date&time.

You can of course use more advanced regexes.

```
^(\d{4}-(11|12|0\d)-(3[10]|[12]\d))[W ]((2[0-3]|[01]\d):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d)$
```

This one tests for valid date and time values (so it doesn't match 27:99:01 anymore), but still matches invalid dates, like 2014-02-31. If you want to exclude those cases, you can access the relevant parts of the match as items of the `match` variable and test for things like number of days of a month and leap years.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is to check whether the string in the format you specified is a valid datetime or not, no need to split it and pass values to some handmade functions, just use this:

```
from datetime import datetime

try:
    valid_datetime = datetime.strptime('2013-01-01W23:01:01', '%Y-%m-%dW%H:%M:%S')
    print 'this datetime is valid'
except ValueError:
    print 'this datetime is invalid'
```